# Externalnterface calls not working in mobile browsers

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, android-webview, externalinterface

I have an **swf** with a simple **ExternalInterface** call. The swf has been created using Flex.

```
ExternalInterface.call("alert","HelloWorld");
```

This runs fine on my machine (without localhost too). 
But when viewed on a mobile browser this does not work.

I need to pass some values from my swf to the native android application (The swf is loaded embedded in html using *Webview*). What could be the best way to achieve the same. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to pass some values to native app how ExternalInterface will help even if it works. I mean when you will get values in browser how you will pass them to native app?

Comment: by passing values from javascript to native app.

Comment: Looks like I need help more than you :D :S. On desktop browsers there is no direct interface to interact with native apps, on mobiles we have such thing? Or you are going to achieve this by sending request from browser after receiving values from flash?

Comment: if only i can get the values from swf :)

Comment: Just to make sure, incorrect embedding causes ExternalInterface.available == false

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459584/im-unable-to-get-externalinterface-call-to-work-in-ie7

Comment: Which mobile browser are you using?  Blackberry?  Or an old version on Android?